# How to prove $H(g)=\{(x,y) : x\in I,\; y=g(x)\}\subseteq \Bbb R^{2}$ is connected, where $g: I \longrightarrow \Bbb R$ is a continuous function?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity

How to prove 
$$H(g)=\{(x,y) : x\in I,\; \; y=g(x)\}\subseteq \Bbb R^{2}
$$ 
is connected, where $g: I \longrightarrow \Bbb R$ is a continuous function.

By the way $I$ is an interval of $\Bbb R$.

I am happy to show more explanatory solution because I cannot understand the solution way. Thank you.

Comment: How can I explain in the way you said? @julien

Comment: To begin with, I guess $I$ is an interval, otherwise this is false.

Comment: Oh ok yes $I$ is interval. I wrote false:/ well, why $I$ is connected? The reason for this is that $I$ is the subinterval of $\Bbb R$. Is this right? @julien

Comment: Yes, you need $I$ to be an interval, otherwise the graph is disconnected. Can you follow my answer below or do you need more explanations?

Comment: In factor I understand the first part. But after the statment "since $I$ is connected", I dont understand enough. Can you explain the second part more if you dont mind? @julien

Comment: Theorem: Let $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ be a map between topological spaces. If $C\subseteq X$ is connected and if $f$ is continuous, then $f(C)$ is connected. Now every interval is convex, hence connected.

Comment: Hmm ok Now everthing is clear:) thank you @julien I understand well thank to you. By the way, You are good teacher. Thank you. I like your teaching way:)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8067/discussion-between-julien-and-b11)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, $H(g)$ is the graph of the function $g$ over $I$. This is the image of the function
$$
G:x\longmapsto (x,g(x))
$$
over $I$. Since $g$ is continuous, $G$ is continuous. And since $I$ is connected as every interval is, it follows that
$$
H(g)=G(I)
$$
is connected as the continuous image of a connected set.